# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android-studio

Estoy trabajando con Andriod Studio Necesito que cada 5 seg se cambie una imagen para ello tengo un timer y ahi hay los cambios pero me sale este error
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Como puedo resolverlo

Este es mi código

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override

            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Ejecuta tu AsyncTask!
                    AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask() {

                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

                            i++;

                            switch (i){
                                case 1:

                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosA();
                                    contImagenes.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
                                case 2:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosB();
                                    contImagenes.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosC();
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosD();
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosE();;
                                    break;
                            }

                            return null;
                        }


                        protected void onPostExecute( ) {
                        System.out.println("Entro al POST");
                        }
                    };


                    myTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Considera cambiar el titulo de la pregunta por una descripcion adecuada del mismo. Pareciera ser solo el error que te salta sin ningun contexto.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que desde un hilo que no es el de la UI no podes modificar la UI, la solucion es simple, solo tenes que usar esto:

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(() -> //Lo que debas hacer);
```

Por lo tanto tu metodo quedaria asi

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override

            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Ejecuta tu AsyncTask!
                    AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask() {

                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

                            i++;
this.runOnUiThread(() ->
                            switch (i){
                                case 1:

                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosA();
                                    contImagenes.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
                                case 2:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosB();
                                    contImagenes.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosC();
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosD();
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                   mostrarImagenesAudiosE();;
                                    break;
                            }
);
                            return null;
                        }


                        protected void onPostExecute( ) {
                        System.out.println("Entro al POST");
                        }
                    };


                    myTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

En el caso que estes ejecutando eso desde un fragment deberas remplazar activity por getActivity()